# How do I prevent interceptor classes from being generated so I can debug?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, debugging, interceptor

I'm using xdebug to set breakpoints in Magento Commerce, which is installed locally on Ubuntu.  I have a breakpoint set in `vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php`.  However, that breakpoint never gets hit because Magento is actually using the class `generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php` when an instance of `FrontController` is requested.  Here's the line in `Http.php` that requests an instance of `FrontController`:

```
$frontController = $this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\App\FrontControllerInterface::class);
```

I tried clearing my `generated/code` directory, but everything within that directory is recreated when I refresh a page.  I am in developer mode.

How do I prevent these interceptors from being used so that I can set breakpoints within my non-interceptor PHP files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can debug. But you need to clear cache.

[image]

There is a Plugin called `front-controller-builtin-cache`. That's around plugin. This plugin will check the content is cached or not. If having cache content, just get the content, don't need to do more.

vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php

```
    $result = $this->kernel->load();
    if ($result === false) {
        $result = $proceed($request);
```

Comment: Thank you.  After clearing the cache, it's working.

Comment: I used redirection in my controller, First initially redirection worked in my controller but then again I hit the same URL the redirection was failed. But once I clear the cache everything works fine again. Clearing cache every time is not possible, do suggest me any idea to overcome this issue. Thanks in advance.